# Cannot compile simple Argonaut expression?

Tags: scala, argonaut

Is this a Scalaz and Argonaut incompatibility issue or is it something else?

```
scala> import argonaut._
import argonaut._

scala> import Argonaut._
import Argonaut._

scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val jsonString: Json = jString("JSON!")
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Memo, but interface was expected
  at argonaut.PrettyParams.<init>(PrettyParams.scala:112)
  at argonaut.PrettyParamss$class.$init$(PrettyParams.scala:252)
  at argonaut.Argonaut$.<init>(Argonaut.scala:3)
  at argonaut.Argonaut$.<clinit>(Argonaut.scala)
  ... 43 elided
```

build.sbt

```
  "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.1",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.4",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently seems to be only compatible with `Scalaz 7.1.1`.